# Start PostgresQL in the foreground on Travis CI

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, travis-ci

I need to start PostgreSQL in the foreground (i.e. `postgres -D path/to/db`). [I have tried this](https://travis-ci.org/BrandonZacharie/node-postgres/jobs/190843533/config):

```
addons
  apt:
  sources:
  - precise-pgdg-9.5
  packages:
  - postgresql-9.5
  - postgresql-contrib-9.5
postgresql: '9.5'
```

which works (`initdb` and `postgres` are in $PATH) but [tests fail with this](https://travis-ci.org/BrandonZacharie/node-postgres/jobs/190843533/config):

```
Error: could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.18174.lock": Permission denied
```

even with `sudo: required`

Update:

`chown -R /var/run/postgresql` [will not work](https://travis-ci.org/BrandonZacharie/node-postgres/jobs/191096529).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock file location can be changed at runtime with the `-c` flag.

```
$ postgres -D /path/to/datadir -c unix_socket_directory=/path/to/socketdir
```

Provide a path to a directory that the current user has permissions for.